# convert arraylist to html table

Tags: java, html, servlets, arraylist

how do i retrieve my arraylist into html table?

my arraylist:

```
[
1, 2011-05-10,  1,  22.0, 
2, 2011-05-10,  2,  5555.0, 
3, 2011-05-11,  3,  123.0, 
4, 2011-05-11,  2, 212.0, 
5, 2011-05-30,  1,  3000.0, 
6, 2011-05-30,  1,  30.0, 
7, 2011-06-06,  1,  307.0, 
8, 2011-06-06,  1,  307.0 ]

out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Counter</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<table border=\"1\">");
        out.println("<tr>");
        for (int i = 0; i < ex.getExpenses().size(); i++) {
            out.println("<td>" + ex.getExpenses().get(i) + "</td>");

            if (i>0 && i%4==0) {
                out.println("</tr><tr>");

            }

        }
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
```

this doesn't really work, since arraylist starts with 0, it gives me the table that looks like this: [image]

how do i get the table that looks like this:

```
1 2011-05-10  1  22.0
2 2011-05-10  2  5555.0 
3 2011-05-11  3  123.0 
4 2011-05-11  2  212.0 
5 2011-05-30  1  3000.0
6 2011-05-30  1  30.0
7 2011-06-06  1  307.0
8 2011-06-06  1  307.0
```

Comment: use a separate counter variable - initialise it at 1 and then check `count%4 = 0`

Comment: Or adjust the condition to draw a new row: if (i>0 && (i+1)%4==0) {

Comment: could you show me where i initialize it in code and loop through it, because i've tried and all i get is a messy table

Comment: thanks, i've just read your second comment and it works well. thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ex.getExpenses().size(); i++) {
        out.println("<td>" + ex.getExpenses().get(i) + "</td>");
        if (i>0 && i%4==0) {
            out.println("</tr><tr>");
        }
    }
```

with

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ex.getExpenses().size(); i++) {
        if (i>0 && i%4==0) {
            out.println("</tr><tr>");
        }
        out.println("<td>" + ex.getExpenses().get(i) + "</td>");
    }
```

By the way. Create separate class `Expenses` that contains 4 fields. It will be much cleaner and easier to convert this to html. You can write special separate method for converting `Expenses` to html table row.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `i` to `(i+1)`:

```
[
1, 2011-05-10,  1,  22.0, 
2, 2011-05-10,  2,  5555.0, 
3, 2011-05-11,  3,  123.0, 
4, 2011-05-11,  2, 212.0, 
5, 2011-05-30,  1,  3000.0, 
6, 2011-05-30,  1,  30.0, 
7, 2011-06-06,  1,  307.0, 
8, 2011-06-06,  1,  307.0 ]

out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Counter</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<table border=\"1\">");
        out.println("<tr>");
        for (int i = 0; i < ex.getExpenses().size(); i++) {
            out.println("<td>" + ex.getExpenses().get(i) + "</td>");

            if (i>0 && (i+1)%4==0) {
                out.println("</tr><tr>");

            }

        }
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
```

Comment: why would you output a useless empty row at the end? And why not i%4==1?

Answer (score -1):

first thing:
    Get arrylist into separate variable and then itarate it with foreach, instead of calling get() and get(i) repeatedly, then change your if condition

```
if ((i+1)%4==0) {
          out.println("</tr><tr>");
     }
```

second thing:
Use `StringBuilder` class to concatenate output string, then print it with only one `out.print`